# How to customize the placeholder in angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-material, placeholder

I am trying to use the placeholder for one of my form field.

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>date</mat-label>
      <input class="date-picker form-control" ngx-mydatepicker
             placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"/>
```

[image]

i get this output. But I donot want the mat-label. However when I remove the label it displays like this
[image]

How do I make this look like the placeholder above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated [here](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#floating-label),

> If you want to create a legacy form field with a placeholder but no label, you will need to specify an empty label to prevent the placeholder from being promoted.

So, you can try following:

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <mat-label></mat-label>
  <input matInput placeholder="Just a placeholder">
</mat-form-field>
```

I created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rkswsb?file=app%2Finput-overview-example.html), please check the most bottom input field.

**UPDATE**

In order to have placeholder in both focused and blured states, you can try to add `*ngIf` statement to `<mat-label>`, which value will be changed by `focus` and `blur` events:

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <mat-label *ngIf="focused"></mat-label>
  <input matInput 
         placeholder="Just a placeholder" 
         (blur)="focused=false" 
         (focus)="focused=true">
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: the placeholder is displayed only if you click. can I make it stay by default